# Unknown column when using subquery result column in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have a few tables I'm joining to select a column for totals using `COUNT()`. This query works great with returning the `total` column:

```
SELECT *,`excel`.`drivers`.`AutoNumber` AS `current_driver`,
(SELECT COUNT(`issues`.`categories`.`points`) FROM `issues`.`points` INNER JOIN `excel`.`drivers` ON `issues`.`points`.`driver_id` = `excel`.`drivers`.`AutoNumber` INNER JOIN `issues`.`categories` ON `issues`.`categories`.`id` = `issues`.`points`.`category_id` WHERE `excel`.`drivers`.`AutoNumber`=`current_driver`) AS `total` 
FROM `issues`.`points` 
INNER JOIN `excel`.`drivers` ON `issues`.`points`.`driver_id` = `excel`.`drivers`.`AutoNumber` 
INNER JOIN `issues`.`categories` ON `issues`.`categories`.`id` = `issues`.`points`.`category_id`
```

But now I'm trying to create a query that compares `total` in there WHERE clause, like this:

```
SELECT *,`excel`.`drivers`.`AutoNumber` AS `current_driver`,
(SELECT COUNT(`issues`.`categories`.`points`) FROM `issues`.`points` INNER JOIN `excel`.`drivers` ON `issues`.`points`.`driver_id` = `excel`.`drivers`.`AutoNumber` INNER JOIN `issues`.`categories` ON `issues`.`categories`.`id` = `issues`.`points`.`category_id` WHERE `excel`.`drivers`.`AutoNumber`=`current_driver`) AS `total` 
FROM `issues`.`points` 
INNER JOIN `excel`.`drivers` ON `issues`.`points`.`driver_id` = `excel`.`drivers`.`AutoNumber` 
INNER JOIN `issues`.`categories` ON `issues`.`categories`.`id` = `issues`.`points`.`category_id` WHERE `total` = 3
```

This returns with an error that `total` is an unknown column. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column aliases cannot be used in `WHERE` clause. Try

```
select a.* 
FROM 
(
SELECT [column_list]
,`excel`.`drivers`.`AutoNumber` AS `current_driver`,
(SELECT COUNT(`issues`.`categories`.`points`) FROM `issues`.`points` INNER JOIN `excel`.`drivers` ON `issues`.`points`.`driver_id` = `excel`.`drivers`.`AutoNumber` INNER JOIN `issues`.`categories` ON `issues`.`categories`.`id` = `issues`.`points`.`category_id` WHERE `excel`.`drivers`.`AutoNumber`=`current_driver`) AS `total` 
FROM `issues`.`points` 
INNER JOIN `excel`.`drivers` ON `issues`.`points`.`driver_id` = `excel`.`drivers`.`AutoNumber` 
INNER JOIN `issues`.`categories` ON `issues`.`categories`.`id` = `issues`.`points`.`category_id`
)a 
WHERE a.`total` >3
```

You can also repeat the whole definition of "total" in `WHERE` - smart optimizer will very likely generate the same plan, but I wouldn't do that for readability sake.

Comment: Perfect. I now have a better grasp of using column aliases, thanks!